# Credible Interval on 2 Random Variables

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, mean, t-distribution, credible-interval

Assuming we have two random variables, $A$ and $B$, each are assumed to follow a normal distribution with **unknown mean and variance**.

A random sample has been drawn from each $A$ and $B$.

How is the 99% credible interval calculated for $E(A - B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are jointly normal? How is that different from the calculation for such interval for $A$ and $B$ if they are independent?

Comment: The independent $A$ and $B$ still are jointly normal, just with $\rho=0$. Do you mean that they are marginally normal but not jointly? // You haven't mentioned a prior distribution, but you did tag the question with both [tag:confidence-interval] and the Bayesian [tag:credible-interval]. Which do you mean?

Comment: @Dave, yes. I would assume the prior distribution is $N (\mu, \sigma)$ with $\mu$ and $\sigma$ being unknown. I meant credible interval, but I thought it might be related to the frequentist-based confidence interval so I have tagged it as well.

Comment: Prior distribution of what, the difference in means? // Do you mean that you assume the two distributions $A$ and $B$ to have normal distributions? Equal normal distributions? That’s not what a Bayesian prior distribution means. That’s a parametric assumption about the data, which might be a totally fine path to follow, but it doesn’t make your methodology Bayesian.

Comment: @Dave, I would assume then it is the parametric assumption about the data. I don't see a prior distribution defined for either $A$ or $B$, however.

Comment: To clarify what it is that you want to know, it would help if you edited your question with how you’d calculate the interval in the case that the distributions are independent. I suspect that what you want to do is calculate a frequentist confidence interval with a parametric assumption about joint normality with correlation.